# Best way to query the array of data stored on the blockchain?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, react

I have an array of transactions stored on the blockchain. I want to show them on the frontend. Should I ask for all of them when the page loads and store them on the frontend and do pagination there or what else should I do? Please help!

Comment: Can you explain the use case better, and related information like the expected array length and such?

Comment: I want to list the transactions of an Ethereum wallet. The count may reach 100 or 1000 or more.

Comment: Depending on the API you are using to get the transaction data, you can implement an appropriate pagination strategy. Its good to have pagination to make sure that your page doesn't load arbitrarily large data.

Comment: What API option do I have if I am using ganache local development blockchain?

Comment: You can use anything like Etherscan, Alchemy or RPC providers